# How to change the bgColor of HTML doc with use of switch w/o using function

Tags: javascript

I want to change the bgColor of my HTML doc with the switch only not with the use of function. 
Plz help. I am a newbie to Javascript. 
My code is like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

var color;
color = parseInt(prompt("Enter the color"));

switch(color)
{
case 1:
        document.bgColor="red";
    break;

case 2:
        document.bgColor="blue";
    break;
case 3:
        document.bgColor="green";
    break;
default :
    alert("invalid");

}


</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

```
var colors = [undefined, "red", "blue", "green"];
var input = parseInt(prompt("Enter the color"));
var color = colors[input];

if(color != undefined) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
} else {
    alert("invalid");
}
```

Instead of passing your input into a `switch`, just use it as the index of an array that has color strings in it.

**Further thought:** If you wanted to map any kind of input to your color output (i.e., not just numerical input), use an object:

```
var colors = {
    1: "red",
    "two": "green",
    "sandwich": "blue"
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = "red"; // just an example
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Comment: You have a typo here.  The string `"<color>"` isn't a valid value for the `backgroundColor` property.  Things like `"red"` and `"rgb(3, 200, 7)"` and `"#4Fcc90"` are.  I'm sure you meant something else.  You should probably fix this answer.

Comment: actually <color> is just a place holder for the actual color.

Comment: @RayToal I think it was supposed to be something like "<write your color here>", but I agree it could be confusing as-is because it looks like an HTML tag.

Comment: Okay then remove the quotes and take it out of code font, or introduce a variable. :)  The OP claims to be a newbie so it is best to be as helpful as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your code `document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;​`

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/wtKuC/)